# How to change the defaut account to link to tfs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 when I cick connect to team foundation server, it asked an account and password for the first time, but then it will use the default account.Now, I want to change the default account, how could I do it? By the way, my os is xp. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on VSTS and select "Run as different user" give the credentials and then connect to TFS.

Comment: Thank you! I did it, but when I check-out, why the user column still shows "Administrator(computername)" ?

Comment: can you atach the screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

These resources may help you:

- [How to Connect VisualStudio 2010 to TFS](http://www.bandgap.cs.rice.edu/classes/comp410/resources/Using%20TFS/How%20to%20connect%20to%20a%20Team%20Foundation%20Server.aspx)
- [Change logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776852/tfs2010-change-connected-user)
- [Automatically connect to TFS under another user account](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/05/21/Automatically-connect-to-TFS-under-another-user-account.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! But I my problem is still exist, is there any other solution?